# Sqlite foreign key

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have four tables namely **driveover**, **tyres**, **error** and **vehicle** in my database. When I insert data into the drive over table, I would like the **drive over id** to be referenced in the table **tyres drive_log**. When I try adding some data to into the database, the **drive_log** remains null and any number I enter is valid though it does not exist in the **drive_over**. I searched online for solutions and I read that foreign keys have to be turned on as they are off by default.
I added the **onConfigure method** in my **SQLiteOpenHelper class** and when I tried to insert invalid data in **drive_log** foreign key constraint does not fail. The **PRAGMA foreign_key=0;** is returned when I tried to check if they are turned on via command line on SQLite so am guessing my foreign keys constraint is not being enabled. My question is, how do I turn on foreign keys?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "allan303.db";
  public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static final String TABLE_DRIVE_OVER = "drive_over";
  public static final String DRIVE_OVER_ID = "drive_over_id";
  public static final String DATE = "date";
  public static final String VECHILE_LOG = "vechile_log";
  public static final String ERROR_LOG = "error_log";

  public static final String TABLE_VECHILES = "vechiles";
  public static final String VECHILES_ID = "vechiles_id";
  public static final String MODEL = "model";
  public static final String YEAR = "year";
  public static final String NUMBER_PLATE = "number_plate";

  public static final String TABLE_TYRES = "tyres";
  public static final String TYRES_ID = "tyres_id";
  public static final String DRIVE = "drive_log";
  public static final String AXLE = "axle";
  public static final String TYRE = "tyre";
  public static final String PRESSURE = "pressure";
  public static final String UNITS = "units";

  public static final String TABLE_ERRORS = "errors";
  public static final String ERRORS_ID = "errors_id";
  public static final String MESSAGE = "message";


  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_VECHILES = "create table " +      TABLE_VECHILES + " ("+ VECHILES_ID + " integer primary key, "
        + MODEL + " text, " + YEAR + " text, " + NUMBER_PLATE + " text " +   ");";


  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ERRORS = "create table " + TABLE_ERRORS + " ("+ ERRORS_ID + " integer primary key, " +
        MESSAGE + " text " + ");";

  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DRIVE_OVER = "create table " + TABLE_DRIVE_OVER+ " (" + DRIVE_OVER_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + DATE + " text, " + VECHILE_LOG+ " integer, " + ERROR_LOG + " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+VECHILE_LOG+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_VECHILES+"("+VECHILES_ID+"), "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+ERROR_LOG+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_ERRORS+"("+ERRORS_ID+"));";

 private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TYRES = "create table "
        + TABLE_TYRES + " ("
        + TYRES_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + DRIVE + " integer, "
        + AXLE + " integer, "
        + TYRE + " integer, "
        + PRESSURE + " integer, "
        + UNITS + " text, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+DRIVE+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DRIVE_OVER+"("+DRIVE_OVER_ID+"));";


 private static Database sInstance;

 public static synchronized Database getInstance(Context context){
    if(sInstance == null){
        sInstance = new Database(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}

  public Database(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

 @Override
 public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}


  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DRIVE_OVER);
      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_VECHILES);
      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TYRES);
      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ERRORS);
}

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    if(oldVersion != newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_DRIVE_OVER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_VECHILES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_TYRES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_ERRORS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss a space after each of your DROP TABLE statements.
This won't allow deleting the existing tables, and the tables won't be recreated.

This

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    if(oldVersion != newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_DRIVE_OVER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_VECHILES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_TYRES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_ERRORS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

should be

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    if(oldVersion != newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DRIVE_OVER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VECHILES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TYRES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ERRORS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

---

Also, in the posted code, there's a missing closing bracket (**}**), which is needed to close the containing Class.

---

Please note that `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` must be increased each time you make strucural changes to your database (i.e.: adding a column to a table).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it and added the closing bracket at the end but it still does not solve my problem. I would like to turn on the foreign keys so that they are referenced in the respective columns I declared when I insert data. I added the onConfigure method but after insertions, the respective columns are left as null. Also the also on the SQLite browser, its displayed as pragma foreign_keys = 0;. If have any idea to solve this, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Did you try adding the spaces? Please note that `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` must be changed to a higher number each time you make strucural changes to your database (i.e.: adding a column to a table)

Comment: Yes, I have added the spaces and I have also changed the version number to 2 but still when I insert data into the database, my foreign key constraint is still disabled. It returns this PRAGMA foreign_keys = "0";